# How can I protect customers' domains from DDOS attack in Multi-tenant App?

Tags: security, dns, multi-tenant, cloudflare, ddos

I have multi-tenant app.
`myproject.com`.
It is using Cloudflare DNS provider to protect from DDOS attack.

Customers will get subdomain like
`customer1.myproject.com, customer2.myproject.com`

And they will be able to connect their own domain by chaning its CNAME or A record.

`customer1.com CNAME => customer1.myproject.com`

`customer2.com CNAME => customer2.myproject.com`

In this case, will Cloudflare protect
`customer1.com` and `customer2.com` as well as `myproject.com`?

If not, what is the best solution for this?

Any suggestion would be  highly appreciated.

Comment: I have not used cloudflare, however any WAF should help you mitigate it. However, you should also be implementing the request rate limiting / throttling patterns to make your code resilient enough by implementation in addition to the the external providers. These also give you a good insight on what tenant consumes more api etc which you can subsequenly use for billing as well

Comment: You mean rate limiting for all my routes?